# CSS centered border

Tags: html, css

Hy everyone,

i want to have a border around a login form in html code, but with my current code, it isn't quite what i want. I want the border to really encapsulate the centered elements. any idea how to do that?

The result looks like this:

[image]

My code:

index.php:

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
<title>Shopping List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</html>
<head>

</head>
<body bgcolor=#878787>

<div class="form">
    <center><h1>Please enter your login details</h1></center>
    <form>
        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" >     </br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="text" name="password" id="password" >     </br>
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
```

style.css:

```
div.form{
text-align: center;

border: 5px solid;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
}

.form label, .form input{
display: inline-block;
}

.form input {
width: 150px;
}

.form label {
width: 100px;
}

input {
border: 5px solid;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;

font-family: Trebuchet MS;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
margin-bottom: 5px;
background-color: #FFF;
padding: 2px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 150px;
height: 30px;
left: 50px; 
}
input:hover {
border: 1px solid #222;
background-color: #EEE;
}
```

Comment: First, `<center>` is deprecated in html5.  remove it and use `text-align: center` styles only.  Second, put your JS into your head, nothing goes before the `DTD` EVER or you throw browsers into `Quirks Mode` which has bad rendering problems in some cases.

Comment: why is your `</html>` smack in the middle of your head section?

Comment: I noticed that you closed the `html` tag before open `head`, you should close at the end of file. After close the `body` tag.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow & moraisandre: Thanks for noticing! mistype. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add

```
.form{
   max-width:320px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works! but can't you let the border figure his width out for itself? if not, thanks anyway!

Comment: @ZenoDhaene If you add a border to an element you can't expect it to be applied on a different element ... which is what you are hoping to do originally

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by reducing the width and centering your container ( div.form )
Something like

```
display:inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: but then it isn't centered anymore :s

Comment: Try combining both, assign the max-width or width with margin: 0 auto and adding the display inline-block as well

Comment: If you can't manage it with playing around with these css changes, try adding another div wrapper so you have one that stretches the entire width and another centered in it. Achieving dynamic bordered area width depending on inner elements width should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS to put a border round whatever you want. for my example i will just surround the username and password fields with a solid black border:

HTML:

```
   <div class="form">
        <center><h1>Please enter your login details</h1></center>
        <form>
            <div class="border"> 
          <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" >     </br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="text" name="password" id="password" >     </br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
```

The only change in the above HTML is i have put div's around the username and password section so the css knows which html to border around.

i then write this simple css:

```
.border {1px solid black;}
```

here a website with will show you what border styles there is out their.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: Please don't use an ID for this. Also please use a more reputable resource than W3Schools such as the Mozilla docs or W3 itself (*Not* affiliated with W3Schools)

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve your issue by updating your CSS a little. Change these rules to the below CSS rules:

```
div.form {
   text-align: center;
}
form {
   padding: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 5px solid;
   border-radius: 25px;
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
}
```

And then updated your HTML to the below HTML:

```
<div class="form">
   <form>
      <center><h1>Please enter your login details</h1></center>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
      <br />
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login">
   </form>
</div>
```

You would then have the following result:

[image]

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for responding!